# Propriedade col-xs não funciona

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Estou desenvolvendo um website utilizando *Bootstrap* e *HTML*, cujo vou deixá-lo flexível
 para a plataforma desktop e mobile. Porém, não consigo entender o porque da propriedade 
 `col-xs`(*phones*) não funcionar.

Segue o trecho de código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>test-Col.xs.md.lg</title>

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
      <div class="card-body p-0">
        <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 ">
            <div class="p-5">

              <form class="user">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-10 col-xs-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-contr   pleRepeatPassword" placeholder="Repeat Password">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                  Cadastrar
                </a>
                <hr>
              </form>
              <hr>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
  <script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Os anexos abaixo demonstram o comportamento da aplicação nas seguintes dimensões: `lg`(*larger desktops*), `md`(*desktops*), xs(*phones*).

Adaptação em `lg`: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adaptação em `md`: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adaptação em `xs`: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por colocar em ambos os campos o código `col-xs-3` acredito que na terceira imagem, os campos deveriam ficar lateralmente posicinados.

**Palpite**: Acredito que o motivo do comportamento em "xs" não estar acontecendo, deve ser por conta dos testes que estou executando, simplesmente reduzindo o tamanho do navegazor clicando e arrastando na vertice do navegador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é mais simples do que parece, pelo que vc vc está indexando no seu documento o `/bootstrap/4.3.1/`. E o motivo para não funcionar é que o tamanho `XS` só existe no Bootstrap 3, no Bootstrap 4 ele não existe e deve ser substituído apenas por `col-n°`.

Então veja que seu grid deveria ficar apenas com `col-3` sem o `xs`

Bootstrap 3: `col-xs-3`
Bootstrap 4: `col-3`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Opções de tamanho do Grid do Bootstrap 4**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu caso com vc declarou a `div` assim, sem um tamanho para `-sm-`:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-2 col-3">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-10 col-3">
```

O grid a partir do tamanho de tela médio `-md-` muda o grid para `col-3`, se vc quiser controlar o tamanho entre `768px` e `576px` vc precisa colocar por exemplo `col-sm-4`, ou então a partir de `-md-` o grid já aplica o `col-3` abaixo de `768px`

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-2  col-sm-4 col-3">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-3">
```

Veja a documentação oficial do grid do Bootstrap 4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Segue o código ajustado.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
      <div class="card-body p-0">
        <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 ">
            <div class="p-5">

              <form class="user">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-2 col-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-10 col-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-contr   pleRepeatPassword" placeholder="Repeat Password">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                  Cadastrar
                </a>
                <hr>
              </form>
              <hr>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Valeu hugo, apesar de já ter visto esse col-nº, não imaginava que ele veio para substituir o `xs`, valeu pela dica do uso do médio `md`, porém, a aplicação só vai ser utilizada por notebook e celular em alguns casos. Acredito que não seria necessário em meu cenário.

Comment: @AndréFilipe talvez sim, talvez não, tem dentro que olha o celular em landscape, tem celular com tela de tamanho de tablet, etc... não sei se vale a pena arriscar só por meia dúzia de caracteres... é só uma opinião, mas faça uma pesquisa com seus usuários para ter certeza ;)

Comment: Na verdade é um único usuário, o *cliente*, que vai usar a aplicação em notebook e mobile, no formato *portrait* apenas.

Comment: Mas vale-se a pena implementar, agradeço!